# Change color of parent li > span when mouse hover on li child ul

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to change color of parent li span when mouse hover on li child ul. (Only CSS)

Html:

```
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-list"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-th"></i> <span>test-menu</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-windows"></i> list-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-windows"></i> list-3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-windows"></i> list-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Css:

```
.menu > li > a:hover > span {
  color:red;
}
```

I tried:

```
.menu > li > a > span + ul:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xk4Ph/1/

Comment: not with css, if you use javascript, it is

Comment: Is it possible with css.

Comment: i doubt it. u can't select a parent element in css3. I assume that's what you are trying to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using CSS only since the `ul` is a child of the `li`... [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJbPs/1/)

Use the following selector:

```
.menu > li:hover > a > span
```

use `:hover` on the `li` instead of the `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your li
`<li class="test"><a href="#"><i class="icon-windows" ></i> list-1</a></li>`
and edit your css : 
`.test a:hover{
    color: #000000;
}`